# How to use DataFrame.isin without the constraint of having to match both index and value?

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have two files one with 6 million entries and the other with around 5 million entries. I want to compare a particular column values in both the dataframes. This is the code that I have used:

```
print(df1['Col1'].isin(df2['col3']).value_counts())
```

This is essential for me as I want to see the number of True(same) and False(different). I am getting most of the entries around 95% as true however some 5% data is coming as false. I extracted this data by using to_csv and compared the columns using vimdiff and they are all identical, then why is the code labelling them as false(different)? Is there a better and more fullproof method?

Note: I have checked for whitespace in the columns as well. There is no whitespace.

PS. The Pandas.isin documentation states that both index and value has to match. Since I have more entries in 1 file, so the index is not matching for these entries, how to remove that constraint?

Comment: You can filter out the False records and then debug accordingly. Also, can you share a sample DataFrame?

Comment: I have taken out the false records and compared by vimdiff. They are all identical. The DataFrame has numbered IDs (5 digit numbers in both the dataframes)

Comment: Even if you remove the index constraint, how are you going to compare 2 columns having different sizes? What is `TRUE`(same) for the 1 million entries you can't compare? Same to what?

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the column you use as parameter inside your `isin()` method as a list.

Then parse it as a copy of your `df1` dataframe because you need to get the value counts at the same column you filtered.

From your example:

```
print(df1[df1['Col1'].isin(df2['col3'].values.tolist())]['Col1'].value_counts())
```

Try running that again.